# C# ExecuteScalar() null COUNT vs SELECT

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand, executescalar

I noticed some odd behavior and hoped one of the experts could explain the difference.  My UI requires an image is unique before presenting it to the user for their task.  I store checksums in the database and query those for unique values.  I noticed that my logic 'flips' depending on whether I use a standard SELECT query vs SELECT COUNT.  I've isolated it down to this line of code but I don't understand why.

SELECT *record* FROM *table* WHERE *checksum = something*

```cs
//This code works correctly (true / false)
Object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
bool checksumExists = (result == null ? false : true);

//Returns TRUE no matter what
Object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
bool checksumExists = (result == DBNull.value ? false : true);
```

I changed to the following SQL for performance against a large table and my logic 'flipped'

SELECT COUNT (*record*) FROM *table* WHERE *checksum = something*

```
//Now this code always returns TRUE
Object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
bool checksumExists = (result == null ? false : true);

//Now this is the solution
Object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
bool checksumExists = (Convert.ToInt32(result) < 1 ? false : true);
```

Does the COUNT statement mean that it will always return a number, even if no rows are found?

Comment: The second example (the one that checks for DBNull) will return false only if a row has been found that matches the where condition but the column _record_ has a null value.

Comment: @Steve right!  SMH. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), *"COUNT( * ) returns the number of items in a group. This includes NULL values and duplicates."*

Comment: @RufusL I get that. I was also trying to make it safe to receive an empty record set. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the COUNT statement mean that it will always return a number, even if no rows are found?

Yes.  Zero is a number. and

```
SELECT COUNT(someCol) c FROM table WHERE 1=2
```

will always return a single row, single column resultset like:

```
c
-----------
0

(1 row affected)
```

COUNT is not the most efficient way to check whether any rows meet a criterion, as it will continue to count them beyond the first.

You can use EXISTS or TOP 1 to generate a query that will stop after finding a single row.  EG

```
   select someMatchesExist = case when exists(select * from table where ...) then 1 else 0 end
```

or

```
select top (1) 1 as someMatchesExist  from table where ...
```

Comment: Would this be considered the ‘best way’ to check for no matches in a large table?